# Entity with either private or protected Id setter creates a new entity on IDocumentSession.Store(entity) instead of updating existing entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ravendb

I'm using MVC3 and my edit controller looks like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Firm firm)
{
    _documentSession.Store(firm); 
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

for some reason, when I set my entity's id like this:
    public string Id {get; set;}

after hitting this controller action and reloading all entities, it does what it's supposed to do, edit the entity.

If I set the entity's Id property to private or protected

```
public string Id { get; protected set; }
public string Id { get; private set; }
```

this same call creates a new entity in RavenDB with a new Id.

Is there some type of setting where RavenDB can work with private or protected setters of Id's?

I don't like the idea of my entity's Id being settable publicly.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Please open an issue about this [here](http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issues#newissue=yes). See if you can attach a failing test it will be all better. This should work, and will be fixed.